# htaccess rewrite material and language on subfolder

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I want to rewrite the address:
`www.mysite.it/en/material-65` to
`www.mysite.it/material/materialDetail.php?id=65&lang=en`

I put this:

```
 RewriteRule ^/(.+?)/material-([0-9]+)$ /material/materialDetail.php?id=$2&lang=$1`
```

on the *.htaccess* file but it doesn't work.

Comment: RewriteRule on htaccess context uses a relative new url  path so Remove the leading slash from your  pattern . Change `^/(.+?)/material-([0-9]+)$` to `^(.+?)/material-([0-9]+)$` .

Comment: Thank you. It works fine

Comment: Now i tried to rewrite the address: www.mysite.it/en/material/pippo to www.mysite.it/material/materialDetail.php?id=pippo&lang=en

I put this 
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/material/(.+?)$ /material/materialeDetail.php?id=$2&lang=$1 [QSA]

on the .htacces file but it doesn't work